# The verb after "makes"

Tags: sentence-construction, parsing

Is the verb `eat` correct or should it be `eats`??

I found a sentence similar to this:

> He makes a student that does not like milk eat a cake with milk

I am not sure if this is a grammatical mistake or the sentence is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subcategorisation frame for *make* (in this sense) is:

> [subject] makes [object] [infinitive clause]

The [infinitive clause] contains a verb in the infinitive (or base) form. Hence 'eat' rather than 'eats', or 'eating', or 'ate', or 'eaten', or 'to eat'.

**Edit**: I'll add that there is no reason for this, or any way you could work it out by logic: it just happens to be a fact about present day English.

Early Modern English allowed a *to-* infinitive clause after *make*, but current English doesn't.

Also, *compel* (with almost identical meaning to *make* in this sense), requires a *to-* infinitive clause, but not a bare infinitive clause: *He compels a student  that does not like milk **to** eat a cake with milk.* The 'to' is required there.

Subcategorisation frames just need to be learnt along with meaning and spelling.